# Find Silverlight Frame control from another cs file

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have  lets say page 1 in a silverlight 4 app with a `Treeview` in one panel and a `Frame` in another panel to navigate to other pages.
When the `Treeview` node is selected it fires an event in a `UserControl` cs file that is the code behind for the `Treeview`.
How do I call on the `Frame` in Page 1 to navigate to someother URI?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is assigning a `Name` to the `Frame` and accessing it via automatically generated field.

If I got you right, this should work:

XAML of the user control:

```
<UserControl>
  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
      <TreeView SelectionChanged="treeView_SelectionChanged"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel>
      <!-- Additional Frame setup omitted for brevity -->
      <Frame x:Name="frame"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code-behind of the user control:

```
void treeView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var targetUri = this.GetTargetUriFromSelectedItem(e); // TODO: implement your target uri retrieval logic
  this.frame.Navigate(targetUri);
}
```

Comment: I had done following to get to home page URL where treeview and frame are located :MainPage rootPage = App.Current.RootVisual as MainPage;  Then string url = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.ToString(); The problem is I want to have a frame on home page navigate somewhere. I dont want to navigate to home page I want Home page myframe navigate to a page within frame. Dont know how to find frame control??

Comment: @rbucha Follow my sample: set `x:Name="frame"` on your `Frame` and then `rootPage.frame` will be the frame. However, this is a very bad design: parts of MainPage should not directly interact with other parts . The better ways include raising events on user controls and handling them on MainPage or using the MVVM pattern.